# htaccess - how to allow multiple ips to access the site

Tags: .htaccess

I'm using this code to allow only my ip to access the site

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
 RewriteRule .* /maintenance.html [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

Now I would like to allow my friends ip to access the site. How to specify multiple ips in htaccess?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use an .htaccess file to restrict the site and add:

```
#...
Allow from IP/SubnetMask
Allow from IP/SubnetMask
#...
```

See [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_access_compat.html#allow) for more details.

Comment: Put it into a directory or location directive, any line.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to add a rule that does nothing for the allowed IPs, than to add the rule for the maintenance; as you can mark the rule as Last, which means next rules won't be processed (unless the rule didn't modify the address, which will trigger one more pass trough the .htaccess). In your case it will look like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxy [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxz
 RewriteRule .* - [L] #do notthing

 #if we are here, the IP is not in the allowed list, redirect
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
 RewriteRule .* /maintenance.html [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding another `RewriteCond` along with adding the `[OR]` flag to the other IP condition:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^yyy\.yyy\.yyy\.yyy
 RewriteRule .* /maintenance.html [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: Basically, when you say IP not 1 OR IP not 2, if you are with IP 1 you are not 2, if you are with 2 your are not 1, so there is no case in which such condition can be satisfied

Comment: @MaximKrizhanovsky Actually the condition is always satisfied regardless of the IP because of what you said, for the conditions is negated it will always return `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what we have been using since 2013

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/maintenance(.+)/(.+)/ maintenance.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance/index\.html?text=Coming+Back+Soon$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^11\.111\.111\.111 [AND]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^11\.111\.111\.112
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png|woff2|ttf)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.cloudianos.com/maintenance/index.html?text=Coming+Back+Soon [R=302,L]
```

The `[AND]` on line 6 is crucial as both IP addresses are negated, hence `[OR]` would not work for both of them. Here's why: `if the IP is not 11.111.111.111 OR 11.111.111.112` will redirect you unless your device is requesting the resource using both IPs (which is practically impossible) since one of the two sides of the `if` will always be true. If the IP is `11.111.111.111` the statement is true as it's not `11.111.111.112` and vice versa.

Here are the conditions of this code:

1. Do not redirect the user if they're already on the maintenance page
2. Redirect the client only if the IP is neither of the two listed (and you'll probably have to whitelist the server's IP as well if you're using PHP of some sort to access file contents remotely, e.g. using CURL)
3. Do not redirect the user if they're viewing a `.css`, `.js`, `.png` etc. file (so that the maintenance page may request the use of such files)