# Restrict access to local address only in the server

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have multiple web application systems in the server and can be accessible through internet using 122.0.0.1 . I want to access one system only in localhost/network without internet connection using 192.0.0.0.

example:
122.0.0.0/abc
122.0.0.0/def
122.0.0.0/ghi 
can access through internet. but i dont want to access 
122.0.0.0/abc through internet. i want to access it using 196.0.0.0/abc online through LAN.

Is this possible? then how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .htaccess file, you can add these lines to only allow specific ip addresses:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from YourIPAdress
```

You could also use this method, include this in your .htaccess or virtual host config file:

Mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23325758/1993548

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxy [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxz
    RewriteRule .* - [L] #do notthing

    #if we are here, the IP is not in the allowed list, redirect
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
    RewriteRule .* /maintenance.html [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This can also be added in your virtual host configuration file.

Comment: how to do that? I 122.0.0.1/abc  , 122.0.0.1/def, 122.0.0.1/ghi can access through internet. but i dont want to access 122.0.0.1/abc through internet. i want to access using 196.0.0.1/abc

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux? Are you under IIS or Apache2 or something else?

Comment: i'm using windows and apache2.4

Comment: ok so each website should have an .htaccess file in its root directory. You can also create a .htaccess file within individual directories if you really want to. With the above method, you can specify an ip address which can access your webpage. For instance * Allow from 192.168.0.45 would let whichever computer which has the ip address of 192.168.0.45 view your website, and any other ip address would be denied. I'll modify this current answer to give you another option to use.

Comment: Did this resolve your issue? If so could you upvote/mark as answer? Thanks!